# CRM 2011 – how to create multiple entity in one request

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I remembered that it's can be done using the SDK and the API, for example:

I wanted to create Task and with the same request (using the same Proxy and Context objects) create a new Contact entity and link in to the Task (RegardingObjectId) – All in one execute / request message to the CRM and of cures with full support of transaction

10X

Itzik

Comment: and of cures with full support of transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it all to be wrapped into a single transaction, you'll have to use a plugin registered either before or after Create, just not in the validation stage.  Then if any action fails, it'll all be rolled back.